# Is electromotive force really a force?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, terminology, history

As far the definition goes emf of [electromotive force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force) is basically potential difference. It even has dimensions of potential. Then why is  it called a force?

Comment: This question may fit better in history of science SE

Comment: You mean to say that it is just a historical fact that it is called a force and there is no physical reason behind it?

Comment: Electromotive force is not always potential difference. It applies also in situations where electric field is not a potential field. It is integral of electromotive intensity (both electric and non-electric) around the circuit. It is called force for lack of better term and for historical reasons.

Comment: Couldn't you find out from an internet search?  Minus 1 for effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Electromotive force (EMF)? How is it related to potential difference?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102259/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*International Handbook of Research in History, Philosophy and Science Teaching*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7bP0AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=electromotive+force+history&source=bl&ots=Beq8TPBx9g&sig=7QQKTKkUbWv7eQdYbxtTB2O4iNU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifgdD71-TMAhXHFz4KHdYuDo44ChDoAQg1MAc#v=onepage&q=electromotive%20force%20history&f=false) quotes the English translation of [Guisasola et al. (2008)](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1806-11172008000100018), which discusses some of the early history of the EMF. The man who coined the term "electromotive force" was [Alessandro Volta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alessandro_Volta), who stated that there was a force separating the charges in current flowing in a closed circuit. He then named this "force"; as a result, his last name is forever attached to the EMF as its unit, the volt.

Answer (score 1):

Electromotive force is not a mechanical force, but a driving electrical force for charges or the potential energy per unit charge stored in the electrical source. It can be seen as the work that can be done by the source to drive off electrons in a circuit, provided there is no internal resistance of the source. This potential is the gradient of the electrostatic force between the electrodes separated by a finite distance within the battery. Otherwise, the work is done by some force which drives the electrons in a circuit. This is why sometimes it is referred to as a "force", but what we mean here is the energy equivalent of the electrical force.